# Creating CSV file with list of data

Tags: java, list, csv

I am writing a code in Java in which data (multiple rows) would be extracted from the database. I would like to store it in a CSV file format. I found out I cannot do something like:

```
ArrayList ls = new ArrayList();
ls.add(col1,col2,col3);
```

***.add*** method would accept only one argument, and, therefore, the above syntax is wrong. I do not want to create a separate class and then provide that object to the ***.add*** method. I have multiple types of values to deal with *(int, String, float)*. Do I want to know how can I implement the same? If there is a way without the requirement of creating a new class, that will serve my purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
ArrayList ls = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(ls, col1, col2, col3, etc);
```

If you are going to write these objects to CSV, then ensure you use a library to handle all corner cases correctly. If you try to simply append values without caring about line endings, delimiter and quote escapes, you are going to have a bad time. Use something like [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial)' CsvWriter to do this for you.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).